# Get user name as variable for aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation

I have a lot of documents in one collection.

My aim would be to generate a view on this collection with a defined `$match` criteria based on the `user name` from the authentication.

This shall not be a parameter for the view.

So that for example a user is performing an aggregation, only a subset of documents will be transferred based on the `$match` in the view.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Aim would be to filter documents based on user group membership stored in another collection

Comment: you can use $lookup for joining two documents

Comment: Correct, and how can I get the Username from the login credential?

Comment: Based on local and foreign filed of UserID. Both documents have to Common UserID field.

Comment: When a user connects, for example mongodb://user1:pass1@host, how can I get `user1` as variable, like `$$USER` ?

Comment: okay. `$$user` is your defined field. and for that you can use `$addFields` aggregate pipeline. If you `User_ID ` are in both documents then i think only `$lookup` is useful for you.

Comment: Ldap authentication ist enabled... How can I get the Username from Login as Variable?